# Linux tool to show SLOC and SLOC modified, added, removed

Tags: metrics, code-metrics

I am currently using the SLOCCOUNT tool for gaining source lines of code (SLOC) for a codebase.

However, it doesnt support comparing two versions of the codebase and then report:

- Lines of code (LOC) modified
- LOC removed
- LOC added

Can anyone suggest a linux based (preferably free) tool to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [CODECOUNT](http://sunset.usc.edu/research/CODECOUNT/) for differencing baselines.  This compares changes, deletions and additions between different code bases.  It's provided free of charge by the University of Southern California.

They only provide source code.  However, it built cleanly out of the zip file in cygwin using g++.  They also claim support for Visual Studio, but I have not tried it.

Answer (score 2):

I beleive `diffstat` utility does that.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) and [SLOC Compare](http://mindx.josefspillner.de/kde/stats/) can show you the trend over time, but it isn't exactly what you are looking for.